# Reset UITableViewCell from a UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have a UITableViewController for searching and user can make a search by date , but I want to let it optional, my problem is that I don't know how to do to reset the UITableViewController after selecting a date, because the UIDatePicker will always let the user choose a new date but not resetting the choosen one here is some screen shots :

[image: search view]

as you can see be default the values are "Tous" which means "All" so the user can let it like that and all fields are optional

[image: Date picker]

and now when you choose the date cell , you are now obliged to choose a date and there is no way to reset the field as you can see

[image: Date fields]

now there is no way to make it the value of the date field to back to "All" , in the other fields since they are strings I just added "Tous" ("All") with the other choices so the user can back to it whenever he wants as you can see here :

[image: String picker]

I don't know how to add an option to the date picker , maybe adding a new button like "today" to reset the field , so you know the problem any one can help please ?

Answer (score 0):

When you show Date picker for Date cell, add one extra button to the toolbar, which will dismiss date picker and set date cell value to "All".

Comment: Thank you , you mean I add a button next to "today" , I thought about that , but I am using ActionSheetPicker and I am afraid that this option is not possible , if you know how please show me the way any way I will try
 https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker

Comment: You will have to modify the code a bit to get this working. Create a subclass of ActionSheetDatePicker and override the customButtonPressed: method.

Comment: I have added a custom button and I implemented the method to handel the action of pressing that button, but I didn't find how to dismiss the UIDatePicker , like when you press the cancel button , do you have any idea how to do that , thanks

Comment: I ended up with changing the method "dismissPicker" to be public , I don't know if it's a bad hack !